# How to install qpython in Windows 10?

Tags: python, qpython

I am unable to pip install qpython.

I have added it to both the environmental path and to the user path.

But it still fails:

[image: error faced]

I want to get the package to be installed so I would be able to continue to do my program.

Comment: Post the error as *text* in the question itself. Images can't be googled. Are you sure you're installing the *correct* package? [qpython](https://pypi.org/project/qPython/) was abandoned 4 years ago. [qpython3](https://pypi.org/project/qPython3/) is the current version. The [qPython github repo](https://github.com/finos/qPython) warns against using the `qPython` package

Comment: It looks like qPython3 is also abandoned, or at least, it doesn't support any [current Python version](https://devguide.python.org/versions/). Why do you need this package? There may be alternatives, like [pykx](https://pypi.org/project/pykx/)

Answer (score 0):

Install `qpython3`, not `qpython`.  [qpython](https://pypi.org/project/qPython/) was abandoned 4 years ago. [qpython3](https://pypi.org/project/qPython3/) is the current version. The [qPython github repo](https://github.com/finos/qPython) warns against using the `qPython` package

> ### Installation
>
> To install qPython from PyPI:
>
> $ pip install qpython3
>
> **Please do not use old PyPI package name: qpython or exxeleron-qpython.**

Comment: Hi i tried, but it did not work same issue.

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Does qPython work with any supported Python version? The docs say `Supported on Python 3.4/3.5/3.6`, all of which are long out of support. The partial screenshot you posted shows pip tried to compile the source because there was no compatible library and failed because some C files were missing. Why do you need `qPython` anyway? If even qPython3 is unsupported, perhaps there are *other* packages that can do the same job?

Comment: Its for work, and my local IT could do it for my colleague but nt me due to this error. He tried taking the package frm my colleague but still could nt